# VBA formula input returns #VALUE - same formula inputted manually returns correct value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

If I input this formula manually it returns the required data:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A7,2)="ID",A8="Account"),MID(A7,FIND(" ",A7,4)+1,FIND(IF(MID(A7,FIND("Posted by ",A7)-1,1)="(","(Posted by ","(Manual Journal: Posted by "),A7)-FIND(" ",A8,4)-2),M6)
```

When inputting within VBA it is entered into the cell as it should but the value displayed is #VALUE:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(AND(LEFT(A7,2)=""ID"",A8=""Account""),MID(A7,FIND("" "",A7,4)+1,FIND(IF(MID(A7,FIND(""Posted by "",A7)-1,1)=""("",""(Posted by "",""(Manual Journal: Posted by ""),A7)-FIND("" "",A8,4)-2),M6)"
```

So, the formula is correct but it's value isn't displayed. I don't understand how this can be when the VBA inputted formula is identical to that inputted manually. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Which cell is `ActiveCell`? The same cell where you manually tried the formula? Make sure you try manually pasting the formula in the exact same cell as VBA tries. Otherwise you didn't test it properly. • The formula string in VBA looks correct to me. • `#VALUE` means the formula could not evaluate properly. • What happens if you let VBA write the formula and then go into this cell press F2 and Enter? Does it show the value then? Is your calculation set to automatic?

Comment: I highly recommend to stay away from using `ActiveCell` when you write a formula with relative references like `A7` etc. Either only use absolute references or make sure you write into a **specific** cell like `Range("A1").Formula = …`. Otherwise this will fail easily.

Comment: The `#VALUE` comes because of `FIND()` When that formula doesn't find the text you are lookng for, it returns `#VALUE`. Yes, you should avoid the use of `ActiveCell` but then also be prepared for that error even when you correctly qualify the range.

Comment: I can't replicate the failure using Excel 365. Entering your formula in a blank sheet in both ways you tried it returns 0 for me in both cells.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The formula when inputted manually works OK, returning the correct value. When I input using VBA it correctly inputs the formula (checked using F2-Enter) but displays #VALUE. The VBA is inputting the correct formula but still displays #VALUE. How could this be?

Comment: I ask again because you didn't answer that yet: Did you test the exact same cell manually and VBA or were those different cells? Make sure you test the exact same cell!